# open(file) from anywhere

Tags: python, macos, file-io

Working on OS X Lion, I'm trying to open a file in my python-program from anywhere in the terminal. I have set the following function in my .bash_profile:

```
function testprogram() {python ~/.folder/.testprogram.py}
```

This way I can(in the terminal) run my testprogram from a different directory than my ~/.

Now, if I'm in my home directory, and run the program, the following would work

```
infile = open("folder2/test.txt", "r+")
```

However, if I'm in a different directory from my home-folder and write "testprogram" in the terminal, the program starts but is unable to find the file test.txt.

Is there any way to always have python open the file from the same location unaffected of where i run the program from?

Comment: What does the `testprogram()` function have to do with the Python program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to make it multiplatform I would recommend

```
import os
open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'rest/of/path/to.file'))
```

Comment: That join is completely unnecessary.  "But multipl..."  You already have slashes as path separators in "rest/of/path/to.file", so how could "~/rest/of/path/to.file" be a problem?

Comment: lol good point ... also python always treats `/` as path separators so meh .. :P

Answer (score 12):

Use the tilde to represent the home folder, just as you would in the `.bash_profile`, and use `os.path.expanduser`.

```
import os
infile = open(os.path.expanduser("~/folder2/test.txt"), "r+")
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Sorry, forgot to add `os.path.expanduser`.

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than referring to a file via anything else besides Python, you need to use an absolute path rather than a relative one.

If you'd like to refer to files relative to the location of the script, you can also use the `__file__` attribute in your module to get the location of the currently running module.

Also, rather than using a shell function, just give your script a shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`), `chmod +x` it, and put it someplace on your `PATH`.

Comment: I use the env method described here regularly.  Depending how you use custom modules, you may need to update your PYTHONPATH as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run the function in a subshell so you can `cd` home before running it:

```
function testprogram() { (
    cd && python .folder/.testprogram.py
) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In python `sys.argv[0]` will be set to the path of the script (if known). You can use this plus the functions in `os.path` to access files relative to the directory containing the script. For example

```
import sys, os.path

script_path = sys.argv[0]
script_dir = os.path.dirname(script_path)

def script_relative(filename):
  return os.path.join(script_dir, filename)

infile = open(script_relative("folder2/test.txt"), "r+")
```

David Robinson points out that `sys.argv[0]` may not be a full pathname. Instead of using `sys.argv[0]` you can use `__file__` if this is the case.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` isn't guaranteed to give the path from the current directory to the script. For example, the script could just be on the user's path.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, huh, `pydoc sys` implies that it is always a path name, but http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html says it might not be. So I suggested to use `__file__` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use either full path like

```
/path/to/my/folder2/test.txt
```

or abbreviated one

```
~/folder2/test.txt
```